# No response with concurrent gremlin client submit

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

In our application, we see that the Gremlin Java Client does not respond when we send beyond 10 concurrent requests to AWS Neptune.
When we submit more than 10 requests concurrently, the Completable future never completes.
Below is the code snippet which creates the cluster

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.build()
                .addContactPoint(clusterEndpoint).channelizer(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.class)
                .port(clusterPort)
                .maxContentLength(CONTENT_LENGTH)
                .maxConnectionPoolSize(MAX_CONN_POOL_SIZE)
                .maxInProcessPerConnection(MAX_IN_PROCESS_PER_CONN)
                .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(MAX_SIMUL_USAGE)
                .enableSsl(true).create();
Client client = cluster.connect();
```

where MAX_CONN_POOL_SIZE & MAX_IN_PROCESS_PER_CONN and MAX_IN_PROCESS_PER_CONN is set to 64

We send the gremlin script as a string to the client using the following java code

```
client.submit(query).all().get();
```

The above call never returns for the 11th request and any subsequent request has the same behavior.
However if i create a new client to the same Neptune cluster the request succeeds till 10 concurrent requests are made.
AWS Neptune cluster config is - db.r4.large
Any idea why this behavior is observed?

Comment: It’s hard to know what might be going on from the information in the question. Can you please add an example of the concurrent code? Also, is there a reason you are sending the query as text and not using Gremlin bytecode? As a note, Sending lots of queries concurrently to that instance type will cause some queuing on the server side. The number of workers on the server will be twice the number of vCPU on the instance.

Comment: FWIW I did a test with a 15 worker ExecutorService pool and had no issues using `Client.submit` concurrently.

Comment: We expose a APi which takes user input and constructs gremlin string, and hence we can not use bytcode. We use very simple queries which are concurrent - Something like - g.V().has('type','host').has('feature', true).order().by('name')

Comment: I agree that the server will queue, but the application can not indefinitely wait.  In our case, once the arbitrary limit hits, the whole WebSocket becomes unusable. Should I create a support SR ?

Comment: Before opening a support case, I have a few more questions. Are any of the queries triggering an exception? If so how are you handling those? What do the server CPU metrics look like?  Are you seeing the pending request queue fill up at all?  This type of query load is very common. Can you share some sample code? The test code I built is working fine.

Comment: One other question - what size of machine are you sending the requests from? I can setup a similar experiment. Note also that the r4-large Neptune instance type               is one of the smallest that Neptune supports. It only has 2 vCPU which means the server will have 4 worker threads servicing query requests. To get higher concurrency you will need to consider a larger instance type at some point.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, None of those queries raise an exception. And in case of exception, we just discard (no retry).  The queries are exactly the same, I changed the property names that's it. We use locust to send the same query with concurrency.
Application is dockerized spring boot application. Yes i agree the neptune cluster is small, but i believe it should have some queing mechanism, our application has 5 minute timeoutes which hit for 11 concurrency.

Comment: You can inspect the queue using `curl https://host:port/gremlin/status` it can hold up to 8K entries. I spent quite a bit of time seeing if I could reproduce this but all I was able to observe was the expected behavior.

Comment: Let me check what is happening in the queue and get back

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I went back and removed Completable future to Mono conversion (which we need to do as we using reactor core) and things are looking good. Do you have any examples to share which demonstrate reactive gremlin drivers. I am yet to debug how my Monos are causing the problem